# Using SQL to concatenate a string + a date/time in a very specific format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string and I am trying to concatenate a date/time on the end, and the date has to be in a very specific format, to match another string.

I have three dates, like this:

```
Oct 13 2017 12:00AM
Aug 1 2017 12:00AM
Aug 1 2017 12:00AM
```

The first date has 19 characters, and just one space between characters.  The second and third, have 18 characters, and just one space between characters.

I tried this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), INTENDDTE, 100)
```

That gives me this:

```
Jun  5 2014 12:00AM
```

That has two spaces between the Jun and the 5!!  I want just one space in between characters, so I can match this to another string.  How can I do that?  I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Date is not string. Please store and process it as date. Then simply format at app layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could use REPLACE like this.

```
declare @date datetime= GETDATE();
SELECT INTENDDTE= REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @date, 100),'  ',' ');
```

I doubt it will be good for performance though.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I ended up using replace, and it works fine.  I was thinking that there should be a more elegant solution, but I guess not.  Anyway, thanks again.